# Powershell start-process can't find file

Tags: powershell

I am trying to upgrade a server with a particular application from a client by PowerShell remote:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server -Credential $mycreds {Start-Process -FilePath "C:\temp\xxx.exe"   -ArgumentList "-default", "-acceptEULA" -wait }
```

Whatever I try, I get messages like "Can't find the file specified..."  what do I do wrong?
FilePath is on the local (client) computer.

Comment: Just to confirm, is the exe on the `$server` or on the computer running the `Invoke-Command`?

Comment: The exe would have to be on the $server.

Comment: You would have to copy it to the client.  You can do it with copy-item and sessions.  If the exe has a graphic interface you won't see it.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. Just for my understanding, how dows it come I can run a PS -script that is on the local machine, but not an .exe ?  This one woks even that the scrpt is only on the lokal machine: 
    $inst = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server -Credential $mycreds -FilePath "C:\scripts\InstalledBssVersions.ps1"

Comment: @ChristerLöwing: if you use `Invoke-Command` with the `-FilePath` parameter in order to run a locally present _script_ file (`.ps1`) remotely, PowerShell *automatically* copies it to the remote machine; from [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command#parameters): "When you use this parameter, PowerShell converts the contents of the specified script file to a script block, transmits the script block to the remote computer, and runs it on the remote computer." - I've also updated the answer with this information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your `C:\temp\xxx.exe` executable must be present on the *server* (the remote machine)** for your command to work, because that is where your script block (`{ ... }`) executes.

<sup>Note: By contrast, if you use `Invoke-Command` with the `-FilePath` parameter in order to run a locally present *script* file (`.ps1`) remotely, PowerShell *automatically* copies it to the remote machine; from [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command#parameters): "When you use this parameter, PowerShell converts the contents of the specified script file to a script block, transmits the script block to the remote computer, and runs it on the remote computer."</sup>

**To copy the executable there from your local (client-side) machine**, you need a 4-step approach (**PSv5+**, due to use of `Copy-Item -ToSession`<sup>[1]</sup>):

- Create a remoting session to `$server` explicitly, using [`New-PSSession`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/new-pssession)
- Copy the local (client-side) executable to that session (the remote computer) with [`Copy-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/copy-item) and its `-ToSession` parameter
- Run your [`Invoke-Command`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command) command with the `-Session` parameter (rather than 
  `-ComputerName`) in order to run in the explicitly created session (this isn't strictly necessary, but there's no need to create another (ad hoc) session).
- Run [`Remove-PSSession`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/remove-pssession) to close the remote session.

**Important**: In a PowerShell remoting session, **you cannot run *external programs* that require *interactive user input***:

- While you *can* launch *GUI* applications, they invariably run *invisibly*.
- Similarly, interactive *console* applications aren't supported (although *output* from console applications *is* received by the client).

However, **interactive prompts *from PowerShell commands* are supported.**

To put it all together:

```
# Specify the target server(s)
$server = 'w764' # '.'

# Establish a remoting session with the target server(s).
$session = New-PSSession -ComputerName $server

# Copy the local executable to the remote machine.
# Note: Make sure that the target directory exists on the remote machine.
Copy-Item C:\temp\xxx.exe -ToSession $session -Destination C:\temp

# Now invoke the excutable on the remote machine.
Invoke-Command -Session $session {
  # Invoke *synchronously*, with -Wait.
  # Note: If the program is a *console* application,
  #       you can just invoke it *directly* - no need for Start-Process.
  Start-Process -Wait -FilePath C:\temp\xxx.exe -ArgumentList "-default", "-acceptEULA"
}

# Close the remote session.
# Note: This will terminate any programs that still
#       run in the remote session, if any.
Remove-PSSession $session
```

---

<sup>[1] If you're running **Powershell v4 or below**, consider downloading **[psexec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec)**.</sup>

Comment: @ChristerLöwing: Unfortunately, `-ToSession` was introduced only in PowerShell v5. You can look into alternatives such as [psexec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec). I've also updated the answer to include this information.